# Stuck on EightQueens Java

Tags: java

I'm having some trouble working on an assignment and was wondering if someone could point me in the correct direction. The project is the eight queens assignment where I need to make a program using recursion to find a solution where 8 queens can be placed on the board without attacking each other.

My output keeps returning something like this:

```
false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, 
true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, 
true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, 
true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, 
true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, 
true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, 
true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, 
true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false,
```

Which is not a valid solution. Here's the checkVertical code I have so far.

```
    public static boolean checkVerticals(boolean[][] board){

            for (int i=0; i<board.length;i++){
                int count = 0;
                for (int j=0; j<board.length;j++){
                    if (board[j][i] = true)
                    count++;
                }

                if (count > 1) {
                    return false;
                }

            }
        return true;

    }
```

Comment: Can you explain the concept of the Eight Queens? when do they attack eachother?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

`if (board[j][i] = true)` should be `if (board[j][i] == true)`

Comment: Or just `if (board[j][i])` because each element of the board 2-d array is a `boolean` anyway.

Comment: Take @R.J's suggestion, but FYI, this is a very common mistake and why you'll sometimes see things like `if(0 == x)`, so that omitting a `=` causes a compile error.

Comment: thanks guys. I'll use R.J's format in the future to avoid this mistake again.